# When an edit causes a post to end up as Low Quality, there should be an option to rollback

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, low-quality-posts, rollbacks

Recently on EE.SE, a question was edited by its author in a way completely incomprehensible: the whole text was completely removed and a weird non-question was left over. The question in question is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/123169/17592) and the edit is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/123169/5).

The question appeared automatically in the Low Quality Posts review queue. I reviewed it, noticed that it was an old post and probably edited, then rolled the edit back and left a comment for the author.

But before I reviewed the post, someone else did, and didn't notice that - he treated it probably as a new question and voted to close it. And so the question ended up in the Close Votes queue.

---

This behaviour seems weird to me. When a post is edited and *that* makes it appear in the Low Quality Posts queue, it should be clearly pointed out that the post was edited. Also, it should be possible to see the revision from the review page, and roll the revision back should be one of the options one has to review.

Now, none of the choices I had really fitted to the situation, so I opened a new tab to rollback the revision, and then clicked 'Looks OK'.

I am aware that this is a very rare case. It will not happen very often that a post automatically ends up in the LQP queue due to an edit, leave alone that the post would actually have been OK before the edit.

However, for those cases, I think it would be good to at least show a notice. Otherwise, people are going to vote to close or delete posts while we could actually do something useful with the post. And if you only show this option when it's relevant (i.e. when the post was edited before getting in the queue), this doesn't make the review layout too complicated.

Disclaimer: I have no clue how often this happens or how much time it will cost to implement the feature I'm requesting.

Comment: This might be better placed on meta.SE instead of meta.SO

Comment: That just looks like a completely fumbled attempt at editing the title.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is far too rare to worry about handling. If it had been a suggested edit by someone other than the OP, I'm confident the edit would have been rejected via the review queue. I doubt that users accidentally deleting the body of their questions happens often enough to need a special way to handle it in the LQ queue.

Comment: Some users deface their questions _intentionally_ to something like "thanks that worked", usually to prevent their instructor from finding out that SO did their homework for them.  That's probably still rare enough to not bother with this feature request, but it does happen.