# How to handle a post sent to low quality queue because OP made a destructive edit?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, rollbacks

On this question: [RC circuit help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270187/rc-circuit-help), OP removed an essential part of his question, making it invalid. Some user then flagged it as "low quality", which seems justified to me.

My question is: how to handle this case appropriately, when I see this from review?

I want to do a rollback, but I can't do it from review (see [When an edit causes a post to end up as Low Quality, there should be an option to rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239726/when-an-edit-causes-a-post-to-end-up-as-low-quality-there-should-be-an-option-t)). If I skip this review item and do the rollback outside from review, the user who flagged certainly won't have his flag marked as "helpful", which seems wrong (although certainly not that dramatic).

Comment: Note: another user made the rollback already. But this probably does not invalidate my question.